# How to interpret this docker registry creation command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry, devops

Is the interpretation of the below command correct?

My Interpretation: Create a registry with name "registry" that listens on port 5002 of container which is mapped to port 5001 of host .

Also, I do not understand what the "registry:2" is required for? Looks like it is "repository_name:tag" which is equivalent to image name. Is this correct?

```
docker run -d -p 5001:5002 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Also, I tried using "registry:1" and "registry:3" which did not work. It works only when I use "registry:2".

```
 ✘  ~  docker run -d -p 5001:5002 --restart=always --name new_registry registry:3
Unable to find image 'registry:3' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/registry
Tag 3 not found in repository docker.io/library/registry

 ✘  ~  docker run -d -p 5001:5002 --restart=always --name new_registry registry:1
Unable to find image 'registry:1' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/registry
Tag 1 not found in repository docker.io/library/registry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/)

- The tags >= 2 refer to the **[new registry](https://github.com/docker/distribution)**.
- Older tags refer to the [deprecated registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry).

The [Deploying a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) page uses the new registry server (with a simpler mapping):

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

This is for localhost access only, since accessing it from other hosts would necessitate ssl certificates.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

---

The [OP Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021611/zack) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712003/how-to-interpret-this-docker-registry-creation-command/33712210?noredirect=1#comment55195833_33712210):

> It seems that it does not work for tags = 3

That is because the [official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) only list the following tags:

> 2, 2.2, 2.2.0 ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image/blob/af287a2a6379ac099edc9c76672abe5cbe2f9469/Dockerfile))

There is no tag 3.

Comment: so docker registry is just like docker hub but here I am using it as a local/private version. So I have a private registry into which I can push any number of images I want to? Also, I tried using "registry:3" and "registry:1" but it did not work

Comment: I just added some more details to my question

Comment: Could you add more details about the first point where you mention "tags>=2" . It seems that it does not work for tags = 3

Comment: @Zack I have edited the answer to address your comment